# Application hangs while running async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am learning about async/await and created a dummy console application. When I try to get the result from async method the program just hangs. Any idea what is wrong in the following code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 5);

    var x = TestAsync();
    //x.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(x.Result);
}

private static Task<int> CalculateValue()
{
        Console.WriteLine("In CalculateValue"); // This line is printed.
        Task<int> t = new Task<int>(GetValue); // The program hangs here.
        return t;
}

public static async Task<int> TestAsync()
{
        int result = await CalculateValue();
        return result;
}

private static int GetValue()
    {
        return 10;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, because the `t` task is never started while being awaited. Add `t.Start();` after creating your task or better change it to `Task.Run(GetValue);` as it's very rare that you need a 'cold' task these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

> ```
>     Task<int> t = new Task<int>(GetValue); // The program hangs here.
> ```

is incorrect, the program actually hangs here :

```
Console.WriteLine(x.Result);
```

`.Result` blocks current thread until task x completes execution and returns result. It never completes as it awaits task returned by `CalculateValue` method whis is this task:

`Task<int> t = new Task<int>(GetValue);`

This is so called 'cold Task' which means that it's a task in an inactive state. 
To start a 'hot' task (which basically means *start* the task) use the `Task.Run` method:

`Task<int> t = Task.Run(GetValue);`